# Finding two centres of array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a two dimensional numpy arrays which describes a list of coordinates where something happens. There are two events on the scene and I would like to calculate where those two are. But I do have difficulties to distinguish those two since there isn't any good pattern from event to event.

Example:

```
[[290, 226],
 [290, 227],
 [290, 228],
 [290, 240],
 [290, 251],
 [291, 252],
 [293, 229],
 [294, 230],
 [ 11, 50],
 [ 11, 51],
 [ 11, 52],
 [ 11, 53],
 [ 12, 50],
 [ 12, 51],
 [ 12, 48],
 [ 12, 53],
 [ 12, 49],
 [ 13, 49]]
```

Obviously, there is something around [290, 240] or so, and something around [12, 50] but I do not manage to find those by searching in the array. Is that already a problem for cluster analysis or is there a clever way to deal with it?

The cluster aren't of similar size, that's purely random.

Edit: Fixed list format

Comment: I think your lists definitely need commas between the numbers.

Comment: You are right, I copied that from the console, sorry. I will fix that

Comment: This may help: https://euanrussano.github.io/20190813kmeans/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are all manner of clustering algorithms and many are implemented in [scikit-learn.cluster](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster). They are well documented and the docs have nice examples, but the various algorithms have trade-offs which can take a while to figure out. For example if you have a general idea about how spaced the clusters are (reflected in the `eps`ilon parameter) you can get good results with DBSCAN:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np

X = np.array(
    [[290,226],
     [290,227],
     [290,228],
     [290,240],
     [290,251],
     [291,252],
     [293,229],
     [294,230],
     [ 11,50],
     [ 11,51],
     [ 11,52],
     [ 11,53],
     [ 12,50],
     [ 12,51],
     [ 12,48],
     [ 12,53],
     [ 12,49],
     [ 13,49]]
)
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=100, min_samples=2).fit(X)
clustering.labels_
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

If you know you have two clusters, KMEANS is good:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

clustering =  KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
clustering.labels_

# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

k-means is also simple enough that you can code it yourself if you don't want to use scikit. Since that's frequently an early assignment in machine learning courses, there are a lot of examples and blogs if you search.

Comment: Thats actually a wonderful answer, it works totally fine and is understandable :) Thank you